# Present facebook albums of a user and allow the user to choose the album from which, pictures will be presented

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, photos

Hi i want to present the albums of a user as links and then the user may choose on an album title. This will redirect him to a page with all of the pictures in the specific album.

This is the code where the titles are presented as links. It works fine but i don't know how to make the other page work with this and present the right pictures.

```
$albums = $facebook->api('/me/albums');

Foreach($albums['data'] as $album) 

{

print ('<a href= "albumPhotos.php">'.$album['name'].'</a>'.'</br>' ) ;

}
```

At the moment the code i wrote presents all the pictures of the user. This is the code bellow..

```
$albums = $facebook->api('/me/albums');
foreach($albums['data'] as $album)
{

     $photos = $facebook->api("/{$album['id']}/photos");
     foreach($photos['data'] as $photo)
     {
            echo "<img src='{$photo['source']}' />", "<br />";
     }
}
```

Please guys is for my dissertation and and i've tried everything!! If you have any clue about this please tell me.

Answer (score 1):

In the albums summary page add a parameter `?album=album_id` to the links to specific albums:

```
// albumsSummary.php
$albums = $facebook->api('/me/albums');    
foreach($albums['data'] as $album)     
{
    print ('<a href= "albumPhotos.php?album_id=">'.$album['id'].'</a>'.'</br>' );
}
```

In the specific album page `albumPhotos.php` check the `album_id` parameter and show only photos from the requested album:

```
// albumPhotos.php
$album_id = $_REQUEST['album_id'];
$photos = $facebook->api("/{$album[$album_id]}/photos");
foreach($photos['data'] as $photo)
{
    echo "<img src='{$photo['source']}' />", "<br />";
}
```

Comment: Apparently it shows a null page in albumPhotos.php but i will try and work it out with the helping code you gave me... Thanks!!

Comment: @EiriniTelevantou, try to debug it: first check if you are getting the right album_id: `var_dump($album_id)`